# Custom Query for CRUD Repo

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, crud, jpql

I have a table `bookreservation` and `book` and I have to fetch reserved book details on the provided date. I have `reservation_date` and `expiration_date` in `bookreservation` table. I'm trying the below custom query using `CRUD/JPA Repository`:

```
@Query("from book b where b.bookid in (select br.book_bookid from bookreservation br where br.reservation_date <=:providedDate and br.expiration_date >=:providedDate)")
public Iterable<Book> findByReservationDateLessThanAndByExpirationDateGreaterThan(Date providedDate);
```

But I'm getting error as:

`Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: book is not mapped [from book b where b.bookid in (select br.book_bookid from br_reservation br where br.reservation_date <=:providedDate and br.expiration_date >=:providedDate)]`

Please suggest me how to fetch these details using this.
Can we use method like this: `findByReservationDateGreaterThanEqualAndExpirationDateLessThanEqual(Date date)`?

Comment: you dont need a "select"? `book` should start in uppercase. Also with `bookreservation`. Means `Book` instead `book`

Comment: In subquery if we remove `select' then how it'll work?
And I think there will be no issue in lowercase or uppercase it'll work for both.

Comment: No, I just was wondering if you dont need a select at the beginning. In subselect you need one. Did you changed `book` to `Book`?

Comment: yeah I tried it.

Comment: does it work or other exception?

Comment: No it didn't work and same exception is coming.

Comment: You are probably trying to execute a SQL query instead of a JPQL... Those aren't the same things.

Comment: How can you say that?

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'join' in the query and correct JPQL. Something like this:

```
@Query("select b from BookReservation br join br.book b where br.reservationDate <= ?1 and br.expirationDate >= ?2")
List<Book> findReserved(LocalDate reservationDate, LocalDate expirationDate );
```

it's assuming that you are using entities like these:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="book")
public class Book {
    //...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="bookreservation")
public class BookReservation {
    //...
    @ManyToOne
    private Book book;
    private LocalDate reservationDate;
    private LocalDate expirationDate; 
    //...
}
```

Comment: Cann't we use subquery?

Comment: You can do [this](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_subqueries), but it is not productive IMHO.

Comment: See the similar [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43276770/5380322) to the neighboring question ))