# join more than one table in spring jparepository

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am trying to fetch record by doing a join. I am new to spring jparepository.
I understand that there is separate repository for each entity(table) where when i implement i need to define the entity and datatype of primary key.

Could anyone please suggest how can I fetch record by joining two tables.

I have two repo as below:

```
public interface AEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<AEntity, Integer>

public interface BEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<BEntity, Integer>
```

I want to join above two entity(AEntity, BEntity). 
I know I can have custom query using something like below:

```
@Query("SELECT ****** FROM AEntity ae")
AEntity findCustomrRecords();
```

However can I write the same kind of query (join query) with join.
Do i need to have a separate repository implementing some other class.

Can anyone please help.

I am using mysql.

Comment: Would you show the relationship between AEntity and BEntity, it is far easier to use Spring JPA than SQL.

Comment: its one-to-one relationship.. for everyrecord in AEntity there will be one record in BEntity.
I want to have a query like
select b.id from a,b where a.id1=b.id1 and a.id2=b.id2 and a.time>b.time1 and a.time<b.time2
Also can I join one more entity(c) where c.id=b.id

I want to join 3 tables which are mapped by id.

Answer (score 5):

> I understand that there is separate repository for each entity(table)

This is a very common misunderstanding. You do not want to have a repository per entity, but per aggregate root. See http://static.olivergierke.de/lectures/ddd-and-spring/

Regarding your specific problem at hand: Creating a custom method in your repository interface and annotating it with a JPQL should do the trick. So you get something like:

```
@Query("select a from BEntity b join b.a a where b.foo = :foo")
AEntity getAllFooishAs(String foo);
```

You can use any [join syntax JPQL offers](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/from) in the query.

Comment: I have 3 tables.
Table1 is mapped with Table2 with a common Id.
Table2 is mapped with Table3 with a common Id.

I want to fetch the records from table3 by combining table1 and table2, and then table2 and table3.

so at the end I should have records from table1 and table3 as a list of Object so that I can separate into AEntity and CEntity.
Each record would have column from table1 and table3. I want to persist the record (combination of table1 and table3) to another table(table4).

Please let me know if it still not clear.

Comment: That is a completely different question.